# C# Need a little assistance with HttpWebRequest Post data

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I basically have some idea how to use HttpWebRequests but I am pretty newbie. So I want to submit the following token with the Post method.

```
authenticity_token=pkhn7pwt3QATOpOAfBERZ%2BRIJ7oBEqGFpnF0Ir4RtJg%3D&question%5Bquestion_text%5D=TEST+TEST+TEST&authenticity_token=pkhn7pwt3QATOpOAfBERZ%2BRIJ7oBEqGFpnF0Ir4RtJg%3D
```

What it does is click a button and send the text "TEST TEST TEST", this is the token I am getting from firebug when I click the button I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send some data with a Http Post Request you can try using the following code:

check 'var serverResponse' for server response.

```
        string targetUrl = "http://www.url.url";

        var postBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(@"authenticity_token=pkhn7pwt3QATOpOAfBERZ%2BRIJ7oBEqGFpnF0Ir4RtJg%3D&question%5Bquestion_text%5D=TEST+TEST+TEST&authenticity_token=pkhn7pwt3QATOpOAfBERZ%2BRIJ7oBEqGFpnF0Ir4RtJg%3D");

        var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUrl);

        httpRequest.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);

        var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse();

        using (var responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            if (responseStream != null)
                using (var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    var serverResponse = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

Comment: On line
 using (var requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
 i get this error: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.

Comment: my bad, I forgot to set httpRequest.Method to POST, see updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```
// you can get the correct encoding from your site's response headers
Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string targetUrl = "http://example.com";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUrl);

var formData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
formData["authenticity_token"] = "pkhn7pwt3QATOpOAfBERZ+RIJ7oBEqGFpnF0Ir4RtJg=";
formData["question[question_text]"] = "TEST TEST TEST";

bool isFirstField = true;
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> field in formData)
{
    if (!isFirstField)
        query.Append("&");
    else
        isFirstField= false;

    query.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", field.Key, field.Value);
}

string urlEncodedQuery = Uri.EscapeDataString(query.ToString());
byte[] postData = encoding.GetBytes(urlEncodedQuery);

request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  

using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    bw.Write(postData);

var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
// TODO: process response
```